# Is there a PhantomJs alternative with css 3d support

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, phantomjs, record

I'm trying to record a webpage using NodeJs. I am using PhantomJs to take screenshots of the page and ffmpeg to conver them to video. The problem is that the page I'm using uses 3d transform css, and PhantomJs does not support 3d transforms (http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html) and everything seems static. 
Is there any alternative to PhantomJs that supports 3d transforms? Or maybe a different approach?

It's not necessary to be NodeJs, other languages like Python works too.

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```js
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 500, height: 860 };

page.open("pageurl", function() {
    // Initial frame
    var frame = 0;
    // Add an interval every 25th second
    setInterval(function() {
      // Render an image with the frame name
      page.render("frames/dragon" + frame++ + ".png", { format: "png" });
      // Exit after 50 images
      if (frame > 100) {
        phantom.exit();
      }
    }, 25);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phantom JS is no longer being maintained so I would suggest using something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which uses headless chrome and gives you the ability to do what you're requesting.

Comment: Thank you. Puppeteer is too slow when taking screenshots. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/476

Comment: If you need to take video you can look into their screencast adaptation, it may work for what your need https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-startScreencast

Answer (score 0):

OBS supports this by way of [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src).  There is an [API for OBS](https://obsproject.com/docs/reference-core.html), or you can use CEF directly.

An alternative method that I use is the [Tab Capture API](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture), by way of browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). It uses chrome and its super fast

They have a simple example code in their readme file

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Run this code here: https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

Also find more information about the `screenshot` command in the docs https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. The problem with puppeteer is that it takes around 100ms to output a screenshot (jpeg), which means that the video will be 10fps ..